# Website looks fine to humans but reports error 500 http status code

Tags: http-headers, runtime-error

This website: http://www.springhillflorist.com.au/shop/ is working fine and has been taking orders for many months.

I was doing some testing (using http://testuri.org/sniffer) and the website was reporting an error 500 status code.

I went back to the website and turned on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and the website is still displaying correctly (with no errors) and the error_log is now logging errors BUT none of them are FATAL - just a few NOTICES and WARNINGS

How could this page be reporting an error 500 but still display perfectly normal?

Comment: Does your site expect some environment or $_GET variable to be set that the sniffer script is not setting, and therefore causing it to error out? Did you check the error log while running the sniffer script?

Comment: Ah, it isn't just the sniffer script - I get a 500 when I open your site and inspect it with my console. Apache could have an error in redirection if you have rewrites or similar going on, or there could be a faulty header() call somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, I figure there's something going on somewhere that's not right but I've got no idea what it could be. I tried accessing a .html file and it works fine as did a basic php file - it's just php accessed through OsCommerce that causing the problems - OsCommerce is past it's use by date...

Comment: i looked at it using Firebug in Firefox, it's almost as if there something in the template is crashing but not disrupting the page output. also, i noticed that you have a bad .js file you may want to fix  - sts_osc_javascript.js - first line is bad "<script language="javascript"><!--". good luck with the 500 error!